# Trying to go through a 2d array, and not getting the correct values?

Tags: java, if-statement, multidimensional-array, int, paint

So currently I am making a maze game, and of course for it to be a maze game it has to have walls. Walls need to stop the player from going over them. I am having a problem checking for collision. It works in some places, and others not. My current method is going through my 2d array, that finds what number the player is attempting to go on by dividing their current x and y by 50, and then using those two numbers to try and see if the player would be colliding with a wall or not. What is happening is that it stops the player from moving for some walls, and some not. In addition it also stops the player in places where there is no wall (a value where it would be 2). I feel like something is getting messed up with the math, but I can't figure out what. Here is the code for how I make the maze, along with the array it is being made from:

```
private int[][] mazeWalls = { //top of the maze
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1},
        {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1},
        {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1},
/*left side*/{1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1}, //right side
        {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1},
        {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1},
        {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
                                //bottom of the maze
};

public void paintMaze(Graphics g){
    for(int row = 0; row < mazeWalls.length; row++){ //example of loops
        for(int col = 0; col < mazeWalls[row].length; col++){ //getting the positions set up
            if(mazeWalls[row][col] == 1){
                g.setColor(Color.RED); //color of the walls
                g.fillRect(col * 50, row * 50, 50, 50); //col times 50 is the x coordinate, and row times 50 is the y coordinate
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for how I check for collision in the same class:

```
public void collisionChecker(int playerX, int playerY){ //takes the user's location and then checks if they are running into the wall
    if(mazeWalls[playerX / 50][playerY / 50] == 1 ){
        setCollision(true);
    }
    else if(mazeWalls[playerX / 50][playerY / 50] != 1){
        setCollision(false); //just in case
    }
}
```

I feel like it should be working, but for some reason (I think it is something with the numbers after dividing the player's coordinates, or something) it is not.

Comment: I believe `playerX` and `playerY` are the coordinates where user clicked and then you are trying to get cooridnates for top left corner of that rectanagle to determine collision or not. Right?

Comment: What are the actual values for playerX and playerY, are they always divisible by 50? If not, that may be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first index in a 2D array is by convention the row index and the second is the column index, so your co-ordinates are the wrong way round:

```
public void collisionChecker(int playerX, int playerY){ //takes the user's location and then checks if they are running into the wall
    if(mazeWalls[playerY / 50][playerX / 50] == 1 ){
        setCollision(true);
    }
    else if(mazeWalls[playerY / 50][playerX / 50] != 1){
        setCollision(false); //just in case
    }
}
```

This code can be simplified to

```
public void collisionChecker(int playerX, int playerY){ //takes the user's location and then checks if they are running into the wall
    setCollision(mazeWalls[playerY / 50][playerX / 50] == 1);
}
```

Comment: I originally thought of doing this, but I decided that it would not do anything (apparently I was wrong, not sure why I did not try this). I can still go over some of the walls, but at this point this seems almost unavoidable with the way I am going about doing this. If you have any idea why this is going on let me know, but your solution did fix it.

Comment: If you are still having problems with the player going though some walls, try taking the player's width and height into account instead of just testing a single point (playerX, playerY). As long as the player is less than one square in size you should be able to just test (playerX + playerWidth, playerY), (playerX, playerY + playerHeight) and (playerX + playerWidth, playerY + playerHeight), assuming that playerX, playerY is the top-left corner of the your player sprite

Comment: I actually just realized that I had the collision check turned on for some directions, while others I had it commented out. That is why I was going over the walls. It works now thank you!